# How to select rows with matching fields in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one with price overrides and one with minute overrides, each per user and product. How can I select them so that I have a record for each user and product?

```
Table 1: Override Prices
+--------+-----------+---------------+
| userID | productID | overridePrice |
+--------+-----------+---------------+
| 4      | 53        | 99.99         |
| 4      | 13        | 99.99         |
| 4      | 55        | 99.99         |
+--------+-----------+---------------+

Table 2: Override Minutes
+--------+-----------+---------------+
| userID | productID | overrideMin   |
+--------+-----------+---------------+
| 4      | 18        | 23            |
| 4      | 55        | 4             |
| 50     | 55        | 2             |
+--------+-----------+---------------+
```

The table I want it to produce:

```
Table 2: All overrides
+--------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| userID | productID | overrideMin | overridePrice |
+--------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| 4      | 13        | null        | 99.99         |
| 4      | 18        | 23          | null          |
| 4      | 53        | null        | 99.99         |
| 4      | 55        | 4           | 99.99         |
| 50     | 55        | 2           | null          |
+--------+-----------+-------------+---------------+
```

I've attempted to GROUP BY `userID`, `productID`, but because product IDs may exist in table 1 that don't exist in table 2, I get different results depending on which `productID` I group by.

Comment: You tried INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UNION`:

```
SELECT userID, productID, 
  MAX(overrideMin) AS overrideMin, 
  MAX(overridePrice) AS overridePrice
FROM
(
    SELECT userID, productID, null AS overrideMin, overridePrice
    FROM OverridePrices
    UNION
    SELECT userID, productID, overrideMin, null AS overridePrice
    FROM OverrideMinutes
) AS t
GROUP BY userID, productID;
```

This will give you the [exact results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/906276/2) you are looking for:

```
| userID | productID | overrideMin | overridePrice |
|--------|-----------|-------------|---------------|
|      4 |        13 |      (null) |         99.99 |
|      4 |        18 |          23 |        (null) |
|      4 |        53 |      (null) |         99.99 |
|      4 |        55 |           4 |         99.99 |
|     50 |        55 |           2 |        (null) |
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using the nested select vs the IF statement mentioned in @vladimir-kovpak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47990821/1285185)? The if statement _seems_ cleaner.

Comment: @bentedder The other answer will not give you the desired output that you are looking for. It will give you the rows and ids from the first table only.

Comment: @bentedder - You can check the results for the other answer here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/906276/4

Comment: Consensus! :) Yeah, this query seems to give me what I'm looking for. I love the internet. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `IF` statement:

```
SELECT
  t1.userID,
  t1.productID,
  if (t2.overrideMin IS NULL, NULL, t2.overrideMin) AS overrideMin,
  if (t1.overridePrice IS NULL, NULL, t1.overridePrice) AS overridePrice
FROM OverridePrices AS t1
LEFT JOIN OverrideMinutes AS t2 ON t1.userID = t2.userID AND t1.productID = t2.productID;
```

But in case you can have different products in table1 and table2 you have to join to table which contains all products, like:

```
SELECT
  t1.userID,
  t1.productID,
  if (t2.overrideMin IS NULL, NULL, t2.overrideMin) AS overrideMin,
  if (t1.overridePrice IS NULL, NULL, t1.overridePrice) AS overridePrice
FROM (
  SELECT userID, productID FROM OverridePrices
  UNION
  SELECT userID, productID FROM OverrideMinutes
) AS t0
LEFT JOIN OverridePrices AS t1 ON t0.userID = t1.userID AND t0.productID = t1.productID
LEFT JOIN OverrideMinutes AS t2 ON t0.userID = t2.userID AND t0.productID = t2.productID;
```

Also, now you can have `GROUP`, `HAVING` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.userID,table1.productID,table2.overrideMin,table1.overridePrice FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.userID=table2.userID AND table1.productID = table2.productID 
UNION SELECT table2.userID,table2.productID,table2.overrideMin,table1.overridePrice FROM table1 
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.userID=table2.userID AND table1.productID = table2.productID 
ORDER BY userID, productID
```

This is the `OUTPUT`

[image]